# Menu bar and toolbar of few applications are very tiny in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, fonts, mendeley

I have recently installed Ubuntu 20.04 on Asus g531gu laptop.

Few applications such as Mendeley and team-viewer have very tiny toolbar and menu bars. I have tried to increase font in setting but to no avail. Below is the screenshot of mendeley desktop application. The Font which is encircled is so tiny it's difficult to read. How do I fix this.

[image]

Some one kindly suggest some fix for this porblem. it has been 18 days.

Comment: You will need to provide some system specs to avoid the need for wild guesses. One of these guesses from my part is that you are running a HiDPI display.

Comment: Spec like what. Its new laptop FHD display with 144hz refresh rate. Does this information help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 20.04 interface font too small after restart, even with high scaling factor](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1269090/ubuntu-20-04-interface-font-too-small-after-restart-even-with-high-scaling-fact)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with high def displays. So, what I simply did was to decrease the resolution from 1920X1080 to 1600X900 now the font is fine with all apps.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue recently on my main rig.  Couldn't find any answers anywhere so I resorted to a fresh install (had originally been a 19.04 install, upgraded later to 19.10, then eventually to 20.04).

The issue hasn't resurfaced on this machine since, but this morning I rebooted the media centre to find the same problem... so I've been back to searching for solutions (incidentially, it was also originally a 19.04 install, so my initial thoughts were that something had gone awry through the upgrades).

As it turns out, it's a bug affecting Nvidia users, so most likely is what's affecting your laptop (nice unit btw).

I found my answer here: [Ubuntu 20.04 interface font too small after restart, even with high scaling factor](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1269090/ubuntu-20-04-interface-font-too-small-after-restart-even-with-high-scaling-fact)

Bug report here: [Shell text is too small in mutter 3.36.4-0ubuntu0.20.04.2](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mutter/+bug/1892440)

I hope this helps.

Comment: Welcome to the community. I have posted my solution to the problem. thnx, nice to know you appreciate my laptop.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what resolved this for me. Adjust the size to your liking. I decided to use a size of 3 on my Pixelbook Go.

```
echo 'export GDK_DPI_SCALE=1.5' >> ~/.bashrc
echo 'export QT_SCALE_FACTOR=1.5' >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
```