# Ubuntu 20.04 built-in display scale option doesn't work on all aplication except the system bars and pointer

Tags: 20.04, display, display-resolution, xrandr

It happened when I unpluged a external 4k monitor. Rebooting and seting xrandr are useless.

screenshot:

- [100% scaling: window big, side bar normal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Okqk9.png)
- [200% scaling: both too big](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVw62.png)
- [`xrandr --output eDP-1 --scale 2x2`: window back to normal scale but the pointer is scaled 200% too and reset back after restart.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uEwOX.jpg)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Menu bar and toolbar of few applications are very tiny in ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1260560/menu-bar-and-toolbar-of-few-applications-are-very-tiny-in-ubuntu-20-04)

Comment: See duplicate question. You experience a bug in mutter. There is a temporary workaround in the question linked.

Comment: @vanadium thx. It shoud be Nvidia driver bug. Using Nouveau and `xrender` can temporarily solve it.

Comment: Happens with me on Intel graphics as well.